# Disable Field with Null Value

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a multiple check-boxes on my Form which when selected disable certain fields.

However, when The value of the field to be disabled is Null or EmptyString, the field will not disable until I enter in a value. Entering a value will disable the field once it loses focus.

I am using the VBA code: ..

```
Me.columnName.Enabled = False
```

Is it possible to disable a field which is null or EmptyString?

Edit: Refactored Sample Code

```
Private Sub Checkbox_Click()

If Checkbox.Value = True Then

    Me.field1 = ""
    Me.field2 = ""
    Me.field1.Enabled = False
    Me.field2.Enabled = False

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I think we need to see more code. I am not able to visualise this

Comment: Ideally, do not use columnName, use controlName. For example, your table may contain Address1, the text box should be, say, txtAddress1

Comment: I've added some sample code to give more of an idea

Comment: What else happens when your code tries but fails to disable a form field?  Does Access give you an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Null is not the same as ""

```
Me.field1 & "" = ""
```

Or cover empty strings and space filled strings with

```
Trim(Me.field1 & "") = ""
```

However, it is unlikely that a field in Access is "" unless you have specifically allowed it, so:

```
If IsNull(Me.Field1) Then
```

Or

```
Me.field1.Enabled = Not IsNull(Me.Field1)
Me.field1.Enabled = IsNull(Me.Field1)
Me.field1.Enabled = Not Me.Checkbox
```

Comment: Checked field using: isNull(Me.field) Then msgbox "field is null" End If. Field is Definitely "" and not Null. Still can't disable field if its empty